# How to submit React form without changing value in field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I am using a React library called Kendo React in order to create a simple form. What I want is to be able to submit my form when the data is changed by clicking on the Load new user button, however the current behavior is that when I click the button and populate with data the submit button does not submit form until I manually change the value of the field, why and how can I just submit the form immediately after I update the data and the button is enabled? Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Form, Field, FormElement } from '@progress/kendo-react-form';
import { Error } from '@progress/kendo-react-labels';
import { Input } from '@progress/kendo-react-inputs';
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/);

const emailValidator = value => emailRegex.test(value) ? "" : "Please enter a valid email.";

const EmailInput = fieldRenderProps => {
  const {
    validationMessage,
    visited,
    ...others
  } = fieldRenderProps;
  return <div>
        <Input {...others} />
        {visited && validationMessage && <Error>{validationMessage}</Error>}
      </div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const handleSubmit = dataItem => alert(JSON.stringify(dataItem, null, 2));

  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    email: 'John.Smith@email.com'
  });

  const loadNewUser = () => {
    setUser({
      firstName: 'NewFirstName',
      lastName: 'NewLastName',
      email: 'NewEmails@email.com'
    });
  };

  return <React.Fragment>
        <button className='k-button' onClick={loadNewUser}> Load new user </button>
        <hr className='k-hr' />
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={user} key={JSON.stringify(user)} render={formRenderProps => <FormElement style={{
      maxWidth: 650
    }}>
              <fieldset className={'k-form-fieldset'}>
                <legend className={'k-form-legend'}>Please fill in the fields:</legend>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Field name={'firstName'} component={Input} label={'First name'} />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Field name={'lastName'} component={Input} label={'Last name'} />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                  <Field name={"email"} type={"email"} component={EmailInput} label={"Email"} validator={emailValidator} />
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <div className="k-form-buttons">
                <button type={'submit'} className="k-button" disabled={!formRenderProps.allowSubmit}>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </FormElement>} />
      </React.Fragment>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because when you use `setUser` a render event is triggered and not a change event on your inputs, so to submit your form on every `loadNewUser`  click,  you can add the submit logic to `loadNewUser` method after `setUser`. The last option is better as you avoid triggering the submit logic before  `setUser` call inside `loadNewUser`.

Or use UseEffect to perform the submit on each change to the user object.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(user);
  }, [user]);
```

Here is a simple example ( without Kendo ) :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const loadNewUser = () => {
    setUser({ name: "alan" });
  };
  const onchange = (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      name: event.target.value
    });
  };
  const submit = () => {
    console.log("submit", user);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    user && submit();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={loadNewUser}>Load new user</button>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onchange}
        value={user != null ? user.name : ""}
      />
      <button onClick={submit}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```